# SVG styling problems with <use>

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to change, with CSS, the size and color of an SVG element that's being rendered with `<use>`. The SVG in question:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="#000000" fill-rule="evenodd" d="<all the actual svg path info>" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

I do not have permission to change the contents of the SVG itself.
The way I'm using the SVG:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#myIcon"></use>
</svg>
```

I've fought with this for hours, read through [a pretty comprehensive article on the subject](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/), and I still haven't had any success. I've tried applying classes to both the `use` element and the outer `svg` element, as well as referencing the `path` element inside. I can't seem to do anything to override the provided styles. How can I change the width, height, and fill color with this arrangement?

Comment: Remove the `fill="#000000"` from the path. Also give the path an `id="myIcon"`

Comment: As stated, I'm unable to change the contents of the SVG itself.

Comment: If you can't edit thr SVG then I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the size it's easy if you correctly set the viewBox and then you adjust the width/height.

For the coloration you can rely on blending mode since the color of the SVG is black.

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.icon::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:var(--c);
  mix-blend-mode:lighten;
}

.icon>svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
<symbol id="myIcon">
    <path fill="#000" d="M81,40.933c0-4.25-3-7.811-6.996-8.673c-0.922-5.312-3.588-10.178-7.623-13.844  c-2.459-2.239-5.326-3.913-8.408-4.981c-0.797-3.676-4.066-6.437-7.979-6.437c-3.908,0-7.184,2.764-7.979,6.442  c-3.078,1.065-5.939,2.741-8.396,4.977c-4.035,3.666-6.701,8.531-7.623,13.844C22.002,33.123,19,36.682,19,40.933  c0,2.617,1.145,4.965,2.957,6.589c0.047,0.195,0.119,0.389,0.225,0.568l26.004,43.873c0.383,0.646,1.072,1.04,1.824,1.04  c0.748,0,1.439-0.395,1.824-1.04L77.82,48.089c0.105-0.179,0.178-0.373,0.225-0.568C79.855,45.897,81,43.549,81,40.933z   M49.994,11.235c2.164,0,3.928,1.762,3.928,3.93c0,2.165-1.764,3.929-3.928,3.929s-3.928-1.764-3.928-3.929  C46.066,12.997,47.83,11.235,49.994,11.235z M27.842,36.301c0.014,0,0.027,0,0.031,0c1.086,0,1.998-0.817,2.115-1.907  c0.762-7.592,5.641-13.791,12.303-16.535c1.119,3.184,4.146,5.475,7.703,5.475c3.561,0,6.588-2.293,7.707-5.48  c6.664,2.742,11.547,8.944,12.312,16.54c0.115,1.092,1.037,1.929,2.143,1.907c2.541,0.013,4.604,2.087,4.604,4.631  c0,1.684-0.914,3.148-2.266,3.958H25.508c-1.354-0.809-2.268-2.273-2.268-3.958C23.24,38.389,25.303,36.316,27.842,36.301z   M50.01,86.723L27.73,49.13h44.541L50.01,86.723z" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<!-- your code -->
<div class="icon" style="--c:red;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 125" width="100">
    <use xlink:href="#myIcon"></use>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="icon"  style="--c:green;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 125" width="150">
    <use xlink:href="#myIcon"></use>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="icon" style="--c:blue;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 125" width="200">
    <use xlink:href="#myIcon"></use>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Save svg as a image with svg format then add the color and width or whatever you want to your img then add this to the html file as a img tag and display: none the svg code.
If you can't reach the html code then you can't do anything.